# WSO2 ESB filter check null for get-property

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to check if a property is null in a filter condition. It might not exist in the context or it can be null as well. I want to cover both cases.
How can I write a filter expression? I tried something like the code below, but it's not working

```
<filter xpath="(get-property('studentId')!=null)">
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

You can check the existence of property by using boolean XPath function as below

```
<filter source="boolean(get-property('yourProperty'))" regex="false">
    <then>
           <!-- NULL OR NON EXIST -->
    </then>
    <else>
           <!-- EXIST -->
    </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: does it check null values as well?

Comment: ```<filter source="boolean(get-property('yourProperty'))" regex="true">
    <then>
           <!-- NULL OR NON EXIST -->
    </then>
    <else>
           <!-- EXIST -->
    </else>
</filter>```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution.

```
<filter source="boolean(get-property('yourProperty'))='null'" regex="false">
    <then>           
           <!-- NULL OR NON EXIST -->
    </then>
    <else>
           <!-- EXIST -->
    </else>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution covers a missing field, null field and empty field validation:

```
<filter regex="true" source="get-property('fieldName') = 'null' or get-property('fieldName') = ''">
        <then>
            [.. error ..]
        </then>
        <else/>
    </filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution also works.

```
<filter source="boolean(get-property('yourProperty'))" regex="true">
    <then>
           <!-- EXIST -->
    </then>
    <else>
           <!-- NULL OR NON EXIST -->
    </else>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet

```
    <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestFilter" context="/test1">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/filter">
      <inSequence>
         <filter xpath="$body//*[local-name()='FilterCondition']/text()">
            <then>
               <log>
                  <property name="ThenCondition" expression="."/>
               </log>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log>
                  <property name="ElseCondition" expression="."/>
               </log>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Try with the sample XML

```
 <Check>
<FilterCondition>123</FilterCondition>

</Check>
```

So your test case should be as below

1: Use the same XML, the flow should go to `then condition`.
2: Pass empty value in `FilterCondition` like `<FilterCondition/>`, this should go to else condition.
3: remove the tag `FilterCondition` and just pass

```
<Check></Check>
```

, this should again go to else condition

Comment: You are not actually checking the property, you are checking a node in the message body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<property
expression="$body//*[local-name()='Address']/text()"
name="Address" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

and then:

```
<filter regex="Tehran" source="get-property('Address')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
    <then/>
    <else>
        <log/>
        <send/>
    </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: This does not answer the original question of checking a property for null value. You are checking a property you know that exists (you set it yourself) against a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template name="TEMPLATE_NAME" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<parameter name="VAR1"/>
<parameter name="VAR2"/>

 <property expression="$func:VAR1" name="REFERENCE_VAR1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<filter regex="true" source="boolean(boolean($func:VAR1 = 'null')   
                     and boolean($func:VAR2 = 'null')   
                     and boolean($func:VAR3 = 'null')    
                     and boolean($func:VAR4 = 'null'))">
    <then>   
         <log category="INFO" level="custom">
           <property expression="$ctx:REFERENCE_VAR1" name="All_NULL"/>
         </log>
    </then>
    <else> 
        <log category="INFO" level="custom">
           <property expression="$ctx:REFERENCE_VAR1" name="NORMAL"/>
         </log>
    </else>   
</filter>
```

Hope this helps